# Why does `tmux` copy operation always output temporary gibberish to the terminal?

Tags: tmux

If I complete a copy operation using `tmux`, I always get one or more lines of gibberish written to my screen, which goes away when I change windows or do a paste.

Why does this happen, and can it be disabled?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default, (for `xterm`-type terminals) *tmux* uses a control sequence to automatically set the external clipboard/selection to whatever is copied. The bulk of this sequence will be the base-64 encoding of the copied data; this is probably the gibberish that you are seeing. It may be that your terminal emulator—the one in which you have attached to a *tmux* session—does not support (and does not silently ignore) this control sequence.

You can disable this *tmux* feature by turning off the `set-clipboard` server option:

```
set-option -s set-clipboard off
```

Search for “set-clipboard” in the man page for the details.

If would not be appropriate to disable this feature for the whole *tmux* server, then you might try using the `terminal-overrides` to modify or remove the `Ms` terminfo capability for certain TERM values:

```
set-option -ga terminal-overrides ',yourTERMname:Ms@'
```

---

Note: If you change your `.tmux.conf` file, be sure to re-`source` it, or restart your server. If you change `terminal-overrides` in an existing server, you will probably have to  detach all clients with matching TERMs before the change will take effect.